# How to use Jackson serialization on toString method?

Tags: java, jackson, spring-aop, lombok

I have already set up an exposed entity class through `Jackson` serialisation, which works well in my `RestController`.

Recently, I tried to create a `Spring AOP` to display the log, but it uses `toString` of the class, which throws `StackOverflow` exception since the class contains a bi-directional relationship.

```
Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    log.debug("Exit: {}.{}() with result = {}", 
        joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
        joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), 
        result);
}
```

How do I set up the `toString` method to use already configured `Jackson` serialisation?

Comment: You may use `ObjectMapper` instead of `toString()` in the logs.

Comment: Than fix `toString` implementation in these classes. `Jackson` will fall in bi-directional fall as well. Of course we can use `JsonBackReference` annotation: [Why do i get an stackoverflow error when using jackson even though using @JsonIgnoreProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55008630/why-do-i-get-an-stackoverflow-error-when-using-jackson-even-though-using-jsonig) and [Searching proper way to convert my two-way linkage between objects to JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853178/searching-proper-way-to-convert-my-two-way-linkage-between-objects-to-json-forma)

Comment: Note: Your IDE is able to generate a decent `toString()` implementation if needed.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Thanks, `ObjectMapper` works pretty well.

Comment: @LunaticJape np. Btw, this is the class used by Jackson for the serialization.

Comment: If, you solved your problem, you can add solution as answer. This way you can accept it later and make it clear that question in answered for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using `ObjectMapper`.

```
Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    log.debug("Exit: {}.{}() with result = {}", 
        joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
        joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), 
        new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(result));
}
```

Comment: It should be noted, for others maybe, that this is a very performance expensive approach, if your toString() is used more often. I would at least make it an class attr. `private final static objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();`